# Finding eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> for the matrix \begin{pmatrix}
> 9 &6&3\\
> 6& 5&0\\
> 3&0&5
> \end{pmatrix} find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues

So I found the characteristic polynomial which is $\lambda(\lambda-5)(\lambda-14)$

for $\lambda=0$ we got \begin{pmatrix}
9 &6&3\\
6& 5&0\\
3&0&5
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
3 &2&1\\
6& 5&0\\
3&0&5
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
3 &0&5\\
6& 5&0\\
3&2&1
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
3 &0&5\\
6& 5&0\\
0&-2&4
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
3 &0&5\\
0& -5&10\\
0&-2&4
\end{pmatrix}

which I manage to bring to \begin{pmatrix}
3 &0&5\\
0& -5&10\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}

Doesnt it mean that I have 2 eigenvectors (the 2 row are linear independent)but the is no algebraic multiplication, so something is wrong

Comment: How did you replace the third row with $0 \ 0 \ 0$? It looks like you subtracted 2 times the third row from the second, but when you do that the third row does not change. If you want to remove the leading $3$ in the third row, you must then subtract $\frac{1}{3}$ times the first row.

Comment: @kccu added the steps

Comment: You have an infinite number of eigenvectors. There’s no such thing as *the* eigenvectors when you’re working with matrices over $\mathbb R$ since any non-zero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector. The eigenspace of $0$ should be one-dimensional, though, as you’ve found from the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

What’s wrong is that you’re misinterpreting the result of your row reduction. The row-reduced matrix has two pivots, and so one row of zeros, therefore its nullity is one—the eigenspace of $0$ is one-dimensional. You can read a basis for this eigenspace directly from the third column of the row-reduced matrix (although you’re less likely to make errors doing this if you continue the row reduction until you have $1$s as pivots).

Answer (score 0):

Your third row after the row reduction should have been $0,6,-12$ (this is what you get from subtracting 3 times the third row from the first one, and of course you exchanged the first and third rows).

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}9&6&3\\6&5&0\\3&0&5\end{bmatrix}&\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}3&2&1\\6&5&0\\3&0&5\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}3&2&1\\0&1&-2\\0&-2&4\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}3&2&1\\0&1&-2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\\
&\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}3&0&5\\0&1&-2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&\dfrac53\\0&1&-2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Thus the solutions are given by $x=-\frac53z,\;y=2z$, and a basis of the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $0$ is, for instance:
$$e=\begin{bmatrix}-5\\6\\3\end{bmatrix}$$